# Cron task in graphic interface

Tags: scripting, x11, cron

I need to open one (or more) browser tab periodically and I decided to use cron.

The command in the shell (bash) that correctly executes this task is `chromium-browser http://mysite.com`. If I type it, the browser opens the site in a tab.

But the same command inserted as a task in the crontable doesn't work.

If I redirect the output of other simple commands in the crontable in a file they work correctly, say

```
echo "hello world" > /home/user/file
```

So, shall I redirect the output of the command `chromium-browser http://mysite.com` to my graphic interface? If yes, which would be the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i added the following to my crontab by typing `crontab -e` and it worked

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome www.github.com
```

My chrome browser opened `www.github.com` every minute. So the following should work for you.

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser http://mysite.com
```